# Should i create a class for a form data?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I have a form that need to be compiled and later edited if the user want. Actually the logic work in that way: i fetch the Json data from the server, use a interface to help me with Intellisense, and after i patch all the data from the Json in the form value (Reactive Form). All the logic is handled inside the component where the form is created. Should I create a class based on the forms value and parse the data of Json in the class? the only problem is that the class will be giant because the form have like 30 field value.

Comment: You might have a bigger problem if you handle a form this big without having any class. By having an interface/class structure, you can create controls and manage the form data easily

Answer (score 0):

First, you should go with multiple classes that mirror the structure of your Json.

Here is a short example :

user.ts :

```
import { PersonalInformation } from './personal-information';

export class User {
  _id: string;
  email: string;
  createdAt: number;
  updatedAt: number;
  personalInformation: PersonalInformation;
  someOtherInformation: SomeOtherInformation
}
```

personal-information.ts :

```
import { Address } from './address';
import { Country } from './country';

export class PersonalInformation {
  avatarUrl?: URL;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  birthDate?:string;
  countryOfResidence?: Country;
  address?: Address;
  phone?: number;
};
```

And define each nested object using the same logic.

Then, to mitigate the complexity of your parent component, you can nest sub-components and manage the validation of some fields in them :

parent-component.ts :

```
let someInformation: SomeInformation = this.sharedService.user.someInformation;

this.parentFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
         countryCtrl: someInformation.accountCountry : '', Validators.required],        
         child: this.formBuilder.group({
           accountNumberCtrl: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]], >>>> YOU CAN SET VALUES FOR YOUR FORM BY REPLACING ''
           [...]
         }),
         additionalInformationCtrl: [(userBankingInformation) ? userBankingInformation.additionalInformation : '']
    });
```

parent-component.html :

```
  <form [formGroup]="parentFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(parentFormGroup)">

    <div>
      <country-search-input [parent]="parentFormGroup" [countries]="countries" [title]="title"></country-search-input>
    [...]
    <div formGroupName="child">
      <account-information [parent]="parentFormGroup.controls.child"></account-information>
    </div>
```

child-component.ts :

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  parent: FormGroup

  // You can do some of the work here
}
```

child-component.html :

```
<div class="some-class-name" [formGroup]="parent">
  <mat-form-field class="some-information-form">
    <input matInput type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+" placeholder="Account number" formControlName="accountNumberCtrl" required>
  </mat-form-field>
  [...]
</div>
```

You can design and put custom validators in other files should you need it.
I hope that helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Yeah my approach about the class actually is the same, the only think that change is that i use only one component to disaply the form, i saw that you splitted the html in other child form component. What's the pro and cons about that? one html with the huge form? or split the form based on his formgroup like: user info, istruction hystory etc...

Comment: The main advantage is readability, because otherwise you end up with a huge template. The only drawback I can think of is having to pass data from child to parent using a SharedService, which is very reasonable in terms of overhead. I am personally not a huge fan of `@Output`. I find it too rigid for most real world use cases. Finally I encourage you to stick with `FormBuilder`, which works really well with complex forms.